# Moving from Azure to Hyperscale

Tags: sql-server, azure

Does Azure Hyperscale allow for Memory optimised tables and does it allow/have rollback facilities

Answer (score 4):

Check out the [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale) on Hyperscale:

> Hyperscale only supports non persistent In-Memory objects (table
>   types, native SPs and functions). Persistent In-Memory tables and
>   other objects must be dropped and recreated as non-In-Memory objects
>   before migrating a database to the Hyperscale service tier.

As for rollback, it depends what you mean. Can it rollback an uncommitted transaction? Yes, it is a SQL Server after all. Can it restore databases to a point-in-time? Yes, [see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale#backup-and-restore) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-service-tier-hyperscale-faq#how-does-the-hyperscale-service-tier-differ-from-the-general-purpose-and-business-critical-service-tiers). For anything else, you'd have to clarify what you mean by rollback.

Comment: That is very useful information.  Thank you.  The first link you suggest discussed connection strings to define ApplicationIntent.  Does this mean that multiple users can access a Hyperscale database with varying connection strings ?

Comment: Hyperscale can have read-only replicas configured to offload read workload. If you have these configured you can include ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly in connection strings for read-only workload to offload this to the read-scale replica.